# Append Text to end of Query Results in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Hello I have a function that is running two queries. I would like to add the letter E to the end of the first Query Results and the Letter B to the end of the query results.

My current function is

```
={QUERY(importRange("*****", "'Inventory'!A3:D"), "SELECT Col2 WHERE ((Col3) > 0)", 1);QUERY(importRange("******", "'Inventory'!A3:D"), "SELECT Col2 WHERE ((Col4) > 0)", 1)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1FpeC9Nck7aGjTEoHg5R0QQBC4S5zj4Yiu_-p0AjvqXY", "'Inventory'!A3:D"), 
 "select Col2 where Col3 > 0", 1)&"E"; QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1FpeC9Nck7aGjTEoHg5R0QQBC4S5zj4Yiu_-p0AjvqXY", "'Inventory'!A3:D"), 
 "select Col2 where Col4 > 0", 1)&"B"})
```