# Append text at the end of a Query in Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, sequence, google-query-language

i'm trying to append the word "End" in the next row at the end of a Query, i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212332/append-text-to-end-of-query-results-in-google-sheets/66212414#66212414?newreg=237ab35e75524d64a69296fb745a5a4e) a code to do it but today this doens't work, add the word at the end of the first column header and do not load the query.

```
=QUERY('PT--------------'!A1:M953,"select * where (I<>'N/A')",1)&"End"
```

Results in:

```
Cash AccountEnd
```

without the '&"end"' it does the Query:

```
Cash Account    Date    Reference   Receipt Payment method  Client ID   Amount  Number of Distributions Invoice Paid    G/L Account Sales Tax ID    TOTAL PAID IN INVOICES  Prepayment
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({QUERY('PT--------------'!A1:M953,
 "where I<>'N/A'", 1); {"End", IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, 12)/0)}})
```